# Английский термин в области кусочно-линейной аппроксимации

Tags: геометрия, локализация, любой-язык, терминология, имена

В программе используется кусочно-линейная аппроксимация. Весь диапазон значений входной переменной разбивается на 1, 2 или 3 участка, в зависимости от внешних условий. 
Каким английским словом назвать **число участков**? Хочу адекватно назвать переменную. Википедия мне не помогла.

Спасибо!

Comment: Предлагаю использовать простое геометрическое слово - Segments.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея!

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку «кусочно-линейная» на английском звучит как «piecewise linear», ваше число — это «number of pieces». В зависимости от соглашений о записи переменных, принятых в вашем языке, это запишется как `numberofpieces`, `numberOfPieces`, `NumberOfPieces`, `number_of_pieces`, `number-of-pieces` и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант! Однако столь длинное имя мне не нравится, т.к. будет использоваться в качестве индекса, и там большие конструкции. Очень желательно что-то из 5-6 символов. А брать NUMBER - как-то очень обезличено. Я думал, есть какой-то термин, более четко отражающий, что именно за число имеется в виду.
Ранее я использовал слово SLICE, но оно явно не в тему...

Comment: @drvlas: В качестве индекса количество использовать как раз не стоит. Потому что количество — это количество, а не индекс. Если вам нужен индекс, используйте другую переменную, например, «current piece index». Кстати, ничего плохого в длинных именах переменных нет. Длинное имя — хорошо, непонятное или хуже того неоднозначное — плохо.

Comment: Спасибо, согласен по обоим пунктам. Но с индексом - не наш случай. В массиве дескрипторов моих переменньіх индексом служит ENUM-имя, в данном случае - как раз SLICE (еще раньше - SLICE_NUMBER, хотя правильнне PIECE_NUMBER). Так что применяемость проверена практикой. А имя дерет глаз перфекциониста... Ну, похоже, так и будет :(

Answer (score 1):

Если имя должно быть коротким, то можно использовать следующие подходы:

1. Общепринятые сокращения.
   Общепринятым сокращением для number является num.
2. Сокращение слов путём убирания всех или некоторых гласных букв.
   Pieces можно сократить до pcs. В данном случае это особенно удачно, поскольку в английском языке это является и общепринятым сокращением, даже гугл-переводчик адекватно переводит "pcs".

Таким образом вашу переменную в зависимости от принятого в вашем языке стандарта можно обозначить одним из следующих вариантов:

num_pcs, numPcs, NumPcs и тд.

При большом желании сделать ещё короче можно ужать num до буквы 'n'.
Это уже менее прозрачный вариант, и если важно, чтобы имя было очевидным, его лучше не использовать.
Однако, обозначение number одной первой буквой в программировании всё-таки часто встречается, и многие программисты могут без комментариев догадаться, что значат имена n_pcs, nPcs и NPcs.

Если же вам всё-таки нужна переменная для индекса, то используйте что-то вроде cur_piece или cur_el (cur - часто встречающееся сокращение от current; el - общеупотребительное сокращение от element)

Comment: Спасибо, оба метода использую. І свой SLICE сокращаю иногда до Slc. Пожалуй, меня подвело только нежелание использовать PIECE как основу для имени. Но вот вижу, что лучшего не нахожу. То есть, сегодня мой вариант будет такой: PcsN (я все-таки люблю piece number, а не number o pieces). Ваш ответ принял, но не могу плюсовать, так как моя статая регистрация на англійском форуме пропала, а здесь я только зарегился.